# Не закрепляются приложения к панели задач Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop

Не знаю, можно ли задавать такие вопросы здесь. Но все же.

С недавнего времени стало невозможным прикрепление каких-либо приложений к панели задач. Причем, открепить тоже не выходит. Ручное добавление ярлыков в директорию `AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` не помогает. Панель не изменяется. Подскажите, можно ли это как-то исправить??? Кнопка для совершения действия присутствует.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте посмотреть [здесь](https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/all/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6/bc1c1ac5-f3e2-4bc2-b74e-957e7cc01ff6) и [здесь](https://viarum.ru/ne-zakreplyayutsya-znachki-na-paneli-zadach/)

Comment: К сожалению, ни один из приведенных Вами способов мне не помог.